# How we are able to create such variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

how are we able to create such variables in javascript? I have never seen variable like this in any other language. It seems like class to me.

```
const me = {
    name:"John Doe",
    org:"XYZ INC",
    codeIn:"python"
};

let echo = `Hi am ${me.name}. I work for ${me.org} and usually code in ${me.codeIn}.`

console.log(echo)
```

Comment: it is just an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Comment: Actually the `me` is a `object` & `name,org,codeIn` are properties of `me` object.

Comment: And const me means me is defined as a constant. That means me is not a variable.

Comment: It is an object? But Its created like a variable there is no class in the code.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
const me = {
    name:"John Doe",
    org:"XYZ INC",
    codeIn:"python"
};
```

is what is called a static object declaration in Javascript.  You can see the syntax described [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).  It creates an object with properties `name`, `org` and `codeIn` that each have their respective values.

Properties of an object in Javascript are accessed with the `.` syntax such as:

```
console.log(me.name)
console.log(me.org);
console.log(me.codeIn);
```

The general idea of an object is that it contains key/value pairs and properties can be referenced as `me.name` or `me["name"]`.  The keys of an object must be strings which is one limitation.  Javascript also contains a `Map` object which allows keys to be of any type (even including other objects).

> I have never seen variable like this in any other language

An object in Javascript is similar in concept to these types in other languages:

```
 struct in C/C++
 struct in Swift
 struct in Go
 struct in C#
 struct in Objective-C
 dictionary in Python
```

> It seems like class to me.

Once created, it is similar in operation to an instance of a class with some already-assigned instance data.  It isn't specifically designed for simple reuse the way a class is.  This syntax is more appropriate for a one-time use for a particular purpose.

If you wanted to create multiple instances each with separate data or you wanted to support inheritance, then you would more likely use a Class definition that provides some infrastructure for creating multiple instances each initialized differently and provides a well documented means of doing inheritance.

Comment: @mike - Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

variable **me** just **Object** it's like associative map when you have key -> value link

variable **echo** it's **Format String** where you can easily insert value of your variables just use **${variable}**. In result you will have insertion of you variable values in this places